# Python replace any word starting with 'lat'

Tags: python

I have been given many different csv files, each containing latitude and longitude data. But their headers are called different names.
Now I would really like to rename the headers, so that they all are called the same. But I dont want to specify every combination that can exist, I only want to rename every column header starting with either 'lat' or 'lon'.

So my headers can look like this:

- **File1 header:** Lat_WGS84, Lon_WGS84
- **File2 header:** Latitude(°), Longitude(°)
- **File3 header:** lat, long
- **etc.**

Now my first thought was to make a `str.replace('lat*','lat')` but this doesn't work, then I tried many combinations of `re.sub()`, but it didn't work for me.

Do anybody have an idea of how to solve this?

Comment: what regex have you tried? `re.sub("^[Ll]at.*","lat",line)` should work

Comment: re.sub(r'lon.\w, ','lon,', str)
re.sub('lon.*,' , 'lon,' str)
re.sub('lon*,' , 'lon', str)

Comment: Surely you just want to replace the first line of every file to `lat, long` no?

Comment: please [edit] your question with a [mcve]. it's currently unclear why it doesn't work

Comment: Why do you need that? And when (at file processing of before any processing)? What about the other columns and what if multiple columns start with lat (`lat_dms` and `lat_dd`)? Currently this is unclear...

Comment: follwoing @Serge Ballesta - if you are sure your column 1 and 2 are always lat and lon your efforts may be directed elsewhere in the project, eg. write a small check for that and forget about differences in initial headers

Answer (score 1):

Using `re.sub`

**Demo:**

```
import re
s = """File1 header: Lat_WGS84, Lon_WGS84

File2 header: Latitude(°), Longitude(°)

File3 header: lat, long 
"""
s = re.sub("lat.*,", 'lat', s, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
s = re.sub("lon.*", r'lon', s, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(s)
```

**Output:**

```
File1 header: lat lon

File2 header: lat lon

File3 header: lat lon
```

Answer (score 0):

```
re.sub("^[Ll]at\w+","lat",line)
```

Hope this helps. Like wise you can make for longitude also.